# How to invoke selenium test into a Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Jenkins.

I have sample selenium code like below in Java project:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SampTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

This works perfect.

I configured like below in Jenkins:
Create a new project with name.
In Advanced options, added Workspace as "D:\UD\ProgrammingSamples\Selenium\SeleniumPractice\src"
In build section, i used Execute Windows batch command like "javac SampTest.java | java SampTest"
(Basically i dont know what to use here. Can someone help me here).

When i build the project now i see an error message saying below:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\UD\ProgrammingSamples\Selenium\SeleniumPractice\src
[src] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson578216989100659838.bat

D:\UD\ProgrammingSamples\Selenium\SeleniumPractice\src>javac SampTest.java   | java SampTest 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" SampTest.java:1: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
SampTest.java:2: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
                                  ^
SampTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        ^
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class SampTest
SampTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
                             ^
  symbol:   class FirefoxDriver
  location: class SampTest
4 errors

D:\UD\ProgrammingSamples\Selenium\SeleniumPractice\src>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you're missing the Selenium jar on your class path. You should either include the jars with `javac -cp '.;/path/to/selenium.jar;' SampTest.java`, or use a dependency management tool for your project, like Maven or Gradle.

Comment: as of now i am interested in include jars in classpath, for that i changed the shell command to "javac -cp 'D:\UD\ProgrammingSamples\Selenium\SeleniumPractice\lib\*' SampTest.java", but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try removing the * after lib.